Globs and variables as arguments to cd
I would like to run the following code in a script.
cd "build_dir/target*/$1*"

I would expect it to cd into the only directory that matches the pattern. Is there a way to do it in general?
P. S.: I run the script with the argument passed, so there's no problem with that.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/600496/how-to-cd-with-word-in-the-middle-of-a-folder

Don't use quotes here: cd build_dir/target*/$1. Otherwise * is used literally.
`

... Rather, don't use quotes around the glob wildcards.  Generally, you do want (double) quotes around the variable reference.  Like this, for example: cd build_dir/target*/"$1"*, or this: cd "build_dir/target"*"/$1"*.  Note well that roughly speaking, everything is a string to Bash, so quotes don't serve to delimit strings as they do in some languages.  They serve strictly to suppress the special lexical significance that some characters have.

Of course, the asterisk must be outside the quotes. But if there is there is more than one matching file, you get a syntax error. I don't know why you are tagging it sh and bash, but if it should run under bash, create an array of all matching entries, and then cd to the first element. Make sure to catch the border case that you have no matching entries.
